# How to change excel sheet specific cell color by using c# loops: If_else

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating a Datatable in C# and export it in excel sheet...How to do in company column cells color by using loops, IF company name is wipro then yellow ELSE red.HELP!

I am trying this code in Visual Studio 2015 but it's not correct,

```
DataTable dt = tablelist.Columns[i];
                if  (DataColumnCollection.tablelist.Column.Company = "Wipro")

                {
                    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red));
                }

namespace Datatable2Excel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable ctr_raw_table = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
            ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(String));
            ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(String));
            ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(String));
            ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
            ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(String));
            string[] row = new string[] { "John", "Wipro", "Engineer", "0203794", "India", "Mumbai" };
            ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "David", "TCS", "Engineer", "02065394", "India", "Thane" };
            ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "Albert", "Infosys", "Engineer", "0206394", "India", "Mumbai" };
            ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "Daniel", "IBM", "Engineer", "02036594", "India", "Mumbra" };
            ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "James", "Accenture", "Engineer", "02560394", "India", "Bhiwandi" };
            ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "Jacob", "L&T", "Engineer", "02036594", "India", "kalyan" };
            ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Export_Ctr_Excel(ctr_raw_table, "Output");
        }
        private void Export_Ctr_Excel(DataTable tablelist, string excelFilename)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            objexcelapp.Columns.AutoFit();
            for (int i = 1; i < tablelist.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[1, i];
                xlRange.Font.Bold = -1;


                int Row = 1;
                int Column = 1;  

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[Row, Column];
                rng.EntireColumn.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.EntireColumn.Font.Italic = true;
                rng.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.HotPink);
                rng.EntireColumn.BorderAround();

                xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

                xlRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = tablelist.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;

                DataTable dt = tablelist.Columns[i];
                if  (DataColumnCollection.tablelist.Column.Company = "Wipro")

                {
                    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red));
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < tablelist.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < tablelist.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (tablelist.Rows[i][j] != null)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1];

                        xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

                        xlRange.Borders.Weight = 1d;
                        xlRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                        objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tablelist.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            objexcelapp.Columns.AutoFit();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            if (Directory.Exists("C:\\CTR_Data\\"))
            {
                objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\CTR_Data\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\CTR_Data\\");
                objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\CTR_Data\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
            }
            objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            foreach (Process proc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
        }

        private object Worksheets(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
    }
}
```

I expect to change cell color by using loops in c# not on excel sheet...i wish when i'll export my data table in excel it will already happens

Comment: Please provide a little more detail in your question. Facts like what are the actual results verses the expected results, what is working and detailed explanation of what is not working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines.

Comment: I want in company column cell color IF company name is wipro then yellow ELSE red all cells..i wish to do it in C# coding under in loops. i know this code is not correct can you please help how to do that                                                             
DataTable dt = tablelist.Columns[i];
 if  (DataColumnCollection.tablelist.Column.Company = "Wipro {
Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)); }
                else{
Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)); }